# Can't disable DevOps pipeline code coverage report

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage

I want to disable the DevOps code coverage report that shows on PRs as I'm using a 3rd party tool as a quality gate.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#configuring-coverage-settings) suggests you can turn the coverage status off in the yaml pipeline configuration like this ([see example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/codecoverage-yaml-samples/blob/master/DisableCodeCoveragePullRequestStatus/azurepipelines-coverage.yml)):

```
coverage:
  status: off
```

However a complete yaml example isn't provided so it's not clear where in the pipeline definition it should be included. I presume it's intended to be used like this:

```
trigger:
- main

coverage:
  status: off

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo "My DevOps Pipeline"
```

Unfortunately when trying to run the above pipeline I get the following error:

> Unexpected property coverage

Is this feature deprecated or has someone else managed to disable the coverage status?

Comment: I first thought it was a typo, but your repeated use of yml indicates you don't know the difference between [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) and [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html). That might come because you are not familiar with the fact the officially recommende extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006 (and some software has still not caught up with that after 17 years).

Comment: @Anthon good pickup, I have updated the question to YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you posted is talking about the *default setting of the code coverage experience for pull requests*. This is configured in a separate `azurepipelines-coverage.yml` at the root of your repo and not in the pipeline YAML.

> If you would like to change the default settings of the code coverage experience for pull requests, you must include a configuration YAML file named `azurepipelines-coverage.yml` at the root of your repo. Set the desired values in this file and it will be used automatically the next time the pipeline runs.

From the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#configuring-coverage-settings) you posted in your question

Comment: Interesting.. I definitely missed this from the doco. Given the test results are published from a pipeline I had expected the coverage policy to be configured in the same pipeline. Thanks for sharing!